# Pygame program crashes handling a tuple

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame

I've coded a small game (just a couple of rectangles moving around) but it crashes during this for loop. It is not an error (like an exception) it just crashes.
It crashes in the for loop when I handle the tuple. If I press SPACE it doesn't even finish the `while` loop, just stops there.
Edit: as requested I added the whole code.

```
 import pygame

pygame.init()
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((400, 300))
uscita = False

v_colpo = 5
v_nemico = 3
v_giocatore = 5
x = 185
y = 270
x_n = 400
y_n = 50
x_change = 0
y_change = 0

indice_colpi = 0
lista_colpi = []
giocatore = pygame.Rect(x, y, 30, 40)
colpo_rett = pygame.Rect(x+5, y, 10, 10)
tupla = []
clock = pygame.time.Clock()
i_colpo = False
while not uscita:

    for event in pygame.event.get():

        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                x_change += v_giocatore
            if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
                x_change -= v_giocatore
            if event.key == pygame.K_SPACE:
                if indice_colpi <3:
                    i_colpo = True
                    direzione = True
                    colpo_rett.x = giocatore.x+10
                    colpo_rett.y = giocatore.y
                    lista_colpi.append((colpo_rett.x, colpo_rett.y))
                    indice_colpi += 1


        if event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
            if event.key in (pygame.K_RIGHT, pygame.K_LEFT):
                x_change = 0


    giocatore.x += x_change
    giocatore.y += y_change
    if giocatore.x < 0:
        giocatore.x = 0
    if giocatore.x > 370:
        giocatore.x = 370


    screen.fill((86, 170, 239))
    pygame.draw.rect(screen, (255, 0, 0), giocatore)
    pygame.draw.circle(screen, (155, 255, 55), (x_n, y_n), 20)
    x_n -= v_nemico

    if x_n < 0:
        x_n = 400

    if i_colpo:
        print(1)
        for colpo in lista_colpi:            
            pygame.draw.rect(screen, (255, 255, 0), (colpo[0], colpo[1], 10, 10))
            print(2)
            lst = list(colpo)
            print(3)
            if direzione == True:
                lst[1] -= v_colpo
            else:
                lst[1] += v_colpo
                if abs(lst[0] - giocatore.x) < 10 and abs(lst[1] - giocatore.y) < 15:
                    print("GAME OVER")

            if lst[1] < 10:
                direzione = True
            if lst[1] > 290:
                i_colpo = True
            t = tuple(lst)
            tupla.append(t)
        print(tupla)
        lista_colpi = tupla

    pygame.display.update()
    clock.tick(25)
```

`lista_colpi` looks like `[(135, 564), (635, 763), (873, 563)]`
The `list` and `tuple` stuff is just to modify the tuple.
What's the problem?

Comment: Can you provide your full code please?

Comment: Okay, just updated it.

Answer (score 2):

Ok so I couldn't solve your issue fully but this is as far as I'm getting for now first you need to declare direzione as you have not done it:

```
i_colpo = False # your code
direzione = False # added
while not uscita: # your code
```

then:

```
if abs(lst[0] - giocatore.x) < 10 and abs(lst[1] - giocatore.y) < 15:
    print("GAME OVER")
```

Needs to be changed to:

```
if abs(lst[0] - giocatore.x) == 10 and abs(lst[1] - giocatore.y) < 15:
    print("GAME OVER")
    break
```

as `abs(lst[0] - giocatore.x)` constantly has the value of 10 and dosent change. `abs(lst[1] - giocatore.y)` will reduce by 5 (mentioned below).

This keeps the game running and your bullets (I'm assuming the yellow square is a bullet) will fire. However this if will constantly fire as there is a problem with your for loop. you have:

```
 lst[1] -= v_colpo
```

this constantly takes 5 off the second element in your tuple and will infinitely reduce as you have no check for if it goes below 0.

As stated before its not 100% but it's a start. Take a look at `for colpo in lista_colpi:` this for loop, it is the source of your problems, not the while loop. Also make use of the python debugger it is immensely powerfull and much better than print statements. Here's my full code in case I added variables etc.

```
import pygame

pygame.init()
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((400, 300))
uscita = False

v_colpo = 5
v_nemico = 3
v_giocatore = 5
x = 185
y = 270
x_n = 400
y_n = 50
x_change = 0
y_change = 0

indice_colpi = 0
lista_colpi = []
giocatore = pygame.Rect(x, y, 30, 40)
colpo_rett = pygame.Rect(x+5, y, 10, 10)
tupla = []
clock = pygame.time.Clock()
i_colpo = False
direzione = False # added
while not uscita:

    for event in pygame.event.get():

        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                x_change += v_giocatore
            if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
                x_change -= v_giocatore
            if event.key == pygame.K_SPACE:
                if indice_colpi <3:
                    i_colpo = True
                    direzione = True
                    colpo_rett.x = giocatore.x+10
                    colpo_rett.y = giocatore.y
                    lista_colpi.append((colpo_rett.x, colpo_rett.y))
                    indice_colpi += 1


        if event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
            if event.key in (pygame.K_RIGHT, pygame.K_LEFT):
                x_change = 0


    giocatore.x += x_change
    giocatore.y += y_change
    if giocatore.x < 0:
        giocatore.x = 0
    if giocatore.x > 370:
        giocatore.x = 370


    screen.fill((86, 170, 239))
    pygame.draw.rect(screen, (255, 0, 0), giocatore)
    pygame.draw.circle(screen, (155, 255, 55), (x_n, y_n), 20)

    x_n -= v_nemico

    if x_n < 0:
        x_n = 400

    if i_colpo:
        # print(1)
        for colpo in lista_colpi:
            pygame.draw.rect(screen, (255, 255, 0), (colpo[0], colpo[1], 10, 10))
            # print(2)
            lst = list(colpo)
            # print(3)
            # print(lst[1])
            if direzione:

                lst[1] -= v_colpo
                if lst[1] < 0:
                    x = 0
                    direzione = False
            else:
                lst[1] += v_colpo
                c = abs(lst[1] - giocatore.y)
                # c = abs(lst[0] - giocatore.x) < 10 and abs(lst[1] - giocatore.y)
                if abs(lst[0] - giocatore.x) == 10 and abs(lst[1] - giocatore.y) < 15:
                    print("GAME OVER")
                    break

            if lst[1] < 10:
                direzione = False
            if lst[1] > 290:
                i_colpo = True
            t = tuple(lst)
            tupla.append(t)
        # print(tupla)
        lista_colpi = tupla

    pygame.display.update()
    clock.tick(25)
```